# Restrict the node local tabs access to specific content types

Tags: nodes, 8, navigation

I have a `module_name.links.tasks.yml` file for Drupal 8, whose content is the following one.

```
entity.node.module_admin:
  route_name: module_name.admin
  base_route: entity.node.canonical
  title: Admin Page
  weight: 99

entity.node.check_backend:
  route_name: module_name.check-backend
  base_route: entity.node.canonical
  title: Check Backend
  weight: 100

entity.node.download_webagent:
  route_name: module_name.download_webagent
  base_route: entity.node.canonical
  title: Download Webagent.conf
  weight: 101

entity.node.download_httpdconf:
  route_name: module_name.download_httpdconf
  base_route: entity.node.canonical
  title: Download httpd.conf
  weight: 102
```

These tabs appear in all the content type nodes. How can I restrict them to  specific content types?

Comment: maybe you need to use the content type path in your routing.yml

Comment: but in routing.yml we only specify the path and controller action for the corresponding route when click on the tab item , we cant filter from there .

Comment: ah, right! hmmmm

Comment: You got any idea ;) ?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, routing is correct. Routes specify access rules, if you want your route to only be accessible for a certain node type, implement custom access callback and check for that.

The local task will then automatically respect that.

Example from core:

```
comment.reply:
  path: '/comment/reply/{entity_type}/{entity}/{field_name}/{pid}'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\comment\Controller\CommentController::getReplyForm'
    _title: 'Add new comment'
    pid: ~
  requirements:
    _custom_access: '\Drupal\comment\Controller\CommentController::replyFormAccess'
```

That method then can receive the same arguments as the controller/form, in your case the node (just add NodeInterface $node) and you can check the type there and everything else you want (like permissions)

Comment: Can you explain the answer with a code sample ? I dint get the area where i can implement custom access callback .

Comment: Core has lots of examples, just search for _custom_access in routing files, added one example

Comment: so in the controller function **'\Drupal\comment\Controller\CommentController::replyFormAccess'** can i do like checking **$node->type== ??** by receiving $node in the controller function?

Comment: Or how i restrict the tab access even i recieve the node type there ?

Comment: See https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/routing-system/access-checking-on-routes#access-custom for a good example.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer !

I have to give like following in `module_name.routing.yml` which will inherit the entity node tabs which are defined in `local.links.task.yml`

```
module_name.admin:
  path: '/node/{node}/module_name'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\module_name\Controller\MyController::my_function'
    _title: 'Admin Page'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access admin tab'
    _custom_access: '\Drupal\module_name\Controller\MyController::admin_tab_access'
```

and in the controller function i am filtering the node types which are only i wanted to display in tab :

```
public function admin_tab_access($node) {
        $node_data = node_load($node);
        if(isset($node_data->field_p_type[0]->value)) {
            $node_type = $node_data->field_p_type[0]->value;
            if ($node_type == 'type_1' || $node_type == 'type_2'){
                return AccessResult::allowed();
            } else {
                return AccessResult::forbidden();
            }
        }
      return AccessResult::forbidden();
    }
```